# Some problems in sorting with array

Tags: c++, sorting

I don't have that much experience in c++ and for some reason this problem seems a bit too much. (I can't use vectors, it has to be arrays)

```
void Main1(int list1[], int list2[], int n, int m, int& temp)

{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (list2[j] % list1[i] == 0)
            {
                for (int k = n; k >= i; k--)
                {
                    list1[k] = list1[k - 1];
                }
                list1[i] = list2[j];
                temp++;
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question. What is the problem with the shown code? Also please provide a complete [mre] including input used, output produced, and output expected. See [ask].

Comment: Using modulus in a sorting algorithm seems odd? What sorting algorithm are you trying to implement? Is there a reason not to just use `std::sort`?

Comment: As far as you code goes, if the `list1` sequence is `n` elements in length, then `list1[k] = ...` invokes undefined behavior on the first k-loop iteration. `k` is initially `n`, which makes it one writable slot *past* the end of your sequence.for `list1`. The same problem happens on the other side of the sequence if the k-loop runs when `i` is 0.